# Could not find openssl on your system on this path: openssl

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ssl, openssl

Estoy intentando guardar datos en mi bdd validando un certificado digital en Node utilizando express y me da el siguiente error

*Error: Could not find openssl on your system on this path: openssl
at C:\Users\User\Documents\EXIMIO\DevWendy\eximio-api\node_modules\pem\lib\openssl.js:237:23*

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de imágenes, pon texto: es más sencillo copiarlo para hacer búsquedas o para crear una respuesta a partir de la pregunta. Por otro lado, es complicado ayudarte si no pones nada de código. Por lo que has puesto asumo que estás usando la librería pem... y parece que no tienes el comando openssl instalado en tu sistema

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentación de pem](https://github.com/Dexus/pem#setting-openssl-location) indica:

> ### Setting openssl location
>
> In some systems the openssl executable might not be available by the default name or it is not included in $PATH. In this case you can define the location of the executable yourself as a one time action after you have loaded the pem module:
>
> ```javascript
> var pem = require('pem') 
> pem.config({
>   pathOpenSSL: '/usr/local/bin/openssl'
> })
> // do something with the pem module
> ```

Que traducido viene a decir que en algunos sistemas has de indicar el path al ejecutable `openssl`. En Windows no viene por defecto, pero lo puedes encontrar como parte de la instalación de [git](/questions/tagged/git), en una ruta similar a

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe
```

Comment: Gracias @PabloLozano  logre resolverlo instalando Openssl on Windows siguiendo la documentación de este enlace: https://medium.com/swlh/installing-openssl-on-windows-10-and-updating-path-80992e26f6a1  en la versión Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1L por que en las superiores tampoco funciona.